# iOS WebApp not showing startup image

Tags: ios, html, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I added

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-screen.png"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

between the head tags of my website
but it doesn't work for the startup image
is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to view the startup image in your desktop browser? If so then I would visit your website on an IOS mobile device and add the app to your homescreen. When you open it you should see the splash screen.

Splash screen are also tricky with different screen sizes. You can use the following code to ensure that it works.

```
        <!-- IOS Touch Icons -->
        <link href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" sizes="57x57" rel="apple-touch-icon">

        <link href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" sizes="72x72" rel="apple-touch-icon">

        <link href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" sizes="114x114" rel="apple-touch-icon">
        <link href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" sizes="144x144" rel="apple-touch-icon">

        <!-- iOS Startup images -->
        <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png" media="(device-width: 320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
        <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
        <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
        <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
        <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
        <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-2048x1496.png" media="(device-width: 1536px)  and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

It is quite tedious to generate all of these images so I would use a tool to generate the different icon and splash screen images automatically.

One such tool would be http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

Answer (score 1):

This functionality appears to have been broken since iOS 9.

Although there hasn't been any official word, this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23924) (and the lack of response from Apple) suggests it is possibly a bug.

The official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW6) (last updated December 2016) still lists the **apple-touch-startup-image** feature so hopefully it will be fixed eventually.