# PWA splash screen fades to black?

Tags: ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen

On iPhone iOS 11.4, when tapping a PWA icon from the home screen, it shows a splash screen, goes to black, then goes back to the splash screen. Not sure why it goes to black, but it can be seen in the PWA example here:

Online demo: https://pwa-splash.now.sh

Github repo: https://github.com/applification/pwa-splash-screens

Source code of demo: https://github.com/applification/pwa-splash-screens/blob/master/index.html

Simply open the online demo link on your phone, add it to your home screen, and click the PWA app icon from your home screen to see the issue with the splash screen.

Any idea how to eliminate the black (so it’s just the splash screen)?

Comment: Please provide the URL here for us to check.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924572/5832311). This might be related to the loading time of the page. Try registering a service worker and do some cache management on the assets involved in the early loading of the app. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#install_a_service_worker) for reference.

Comment: @Anand I had linked it, but I added more relevant direct links.

Comment: @abielita The linked example is pretty small I think, it used to work before the ios upgrade without the fade, but you can see it's still there on the linked small example.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested in iOS 11.4 (iPhone x resolution) and all I saw was the default white splash screen and not the image which is linked via "apple-touch-startup-image".

In the code, I did not see any resolution supporting iPhone X's(2436-by-1125) which answered the behavior.

Please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431209/1057093) to support more higher resolution to make it work in your resolution and all possible iOS devices.

Comment: tbh, I am confused by your linked answer. The code portion there under `iOS Startup images` lists 6 `apple-touch-startup-image` variations, but those wXh numbers don't match the numbers on apple's launch screen docs: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/ In the bottom of the apple doc, it currently lists 12 device size variations, and 24 for both orientations, landscape and horizontal. Not really sure if that answer is outdated or how to apply it to work with all the apple doc screen sizes?

Comment: One more answer in the same link suggests that this solution is not working anymore though Apple document still lists these syntax. I believe we do not have any solution for latest iOS and have to wait on Apple supporting W3C spec like chrome. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries and thank you for your comment. I'll leave this question open in case a modern answer solves it :)